# How to reset \renewcommand\l{\lambda} locally

Tags: macros, grouping

I have a large document with a lot of equation, the author overwritten the original `\l` (used to get polish letter ł) with `\renewcommand\l{{\lambda}}`. It would be to much work to find all the `\l` in all the equations and change it to `\lambda`. I only need couple of ł it the entire doc so I need to reset locally the `\l` command. How do I do that? `\renewcommand\l{???}`

Comment: Would search and replace help, perhaps using regular expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot reset a `\renewcommand`. But there are several options.

The cleanest would be to write `ł` instead of `\l` directly. This merely requires saving the document as UTF-8 and either using a modern LaTeX processor (LuaTeX or XeLaTeX) or to include the `inputenc` package with the `utf8` option (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`).

Alternatively, you can define a *new* command to include `\l` immediately before it’s redefined:

```
\let\lw\l
\renewcommand\l{{\lambda}}
```

… and then just use `\lw` in place of `\l` to typeset ł.

Or you could change the redefinition of `\l` so that it only includes the λ in math mode, and includes ł in text mode. But I wouldn’t do that – it’s very unintuitive and hard to understand as a reader of the source code. Still, here it is:

```
\let\oldl\l
\renewcommand\l{\relax\iffmode\lambda\else\oldl\fi}

% … usage:

Here’s a z\l oty for your effort. $\l = 1\ \mL$
```

… which will render as:

> Here’s a złoty for your effort. λ = 1 µL

Comment: It would be better to use `\LetLtxMacro\oldl\l` (requires loading the `letltxmacro` package) and `\DeclareRobustCommand{\l}{\ifmmode\lambda\else\oldl\fi}`

Comment: Hey Konrad, all your suggestions work, I choose the first one since it's the fastest, but I like the one with it being different command if it's in math mode, very clever. Thank You! You saved me days of work this being a 700 page book!